# The limits of the sum of functions whose limits do not exist

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have a homework problem that I'm not sure how to start. I tried Google for similar examples it didn't turn up anything. Could someone tell me the name of the concept to look into? The problem is as follows:

Show by example that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) + g(x)$ can exist even if both $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ do not exist.

Comment: Set $g=-f$ for an appropriate $f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$, and $c=0$. We note that clearly

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x} \text{ d.n.e}$$

and that

$$\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{1}{x} \text{ d.n.e}$$

However

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)+g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake, the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\tfrac1x$ does not exist since $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\tfrac1x=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\tfrac1x=-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct, I have edited the response.

Comment: That's great, +1! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}.$$
Now try to find a corresponding $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $c=0,$ $f,g:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to\mathbb{R},$ $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x} , g(x) =-\sin\frac{1}{x} .$

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$.  Neither limit as $x\to\infty$ exists as a real number, yet the limit of the sum is $0$.  Or $f(x)=sinx$ and $g(x)=-sinx$.  This time neither limit exists (as a real number OR +/-$\infty$, but the limit of the sum is $0$.

To get this phenomenon as $x$ approaches some real number $c$, think of a function $f$ with a vertical asymptote at $x=c$, and then take that function's negation as $g$.